# DataSet Merge and AcceptChanges to get DiffGram

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I have two XML data sets, ds1 and ds2.  I read these data sets with .ReadXML(name, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema).  I am trying to get a DiffGram with the differences between the two by using a merged data set as shown below.

```
DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
ds3.Merge(ds1);
ds3.AcceptChanges();
ds3.Merge(ds2);

DataSet ds4 = ds3.GetChanges();

ds4.WriteXml("ds4.xml", XmlWriteMode.DiffGram);
```

ds1 and ds2 each contains multiple elements.  I created ds2 by copying the ds1 file and modifying one of the records.

However, when I look at ds4.xml after execution, it shows all of the record sets in ds1 and all of the records in ds2 (so it shows duplicate entries), and the ds2 updates are listed as ...diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">.  It seems that this is only inserting, not updating existing records.

How can I get ds4 to only show the change that was made in ds2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior of inserting versus updating typically occurs due to the lack of defined primary keys. Have you set primary keys on the tables? That's how the columns are matched up during a merge. [Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> When merging a new source DataSet into
>   the target, any source rows with a
>   DataRowState value of Unchanged,
>   Modified, or Deleted are **matched to
>   target rows with the same primary key
>   values**. Source rows with a
>   DataRowState value of Added are
>   **matched to new target rows with the
>   same primary key values** as the new
>   source rows.

Therefore, for each `DataTable` you should set the [`PrimaryKey` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx). I wrote a detailed example of this on the MSDN `DataTable.Merge` page a few years ago. You can take a look at that write up here: [Merge using Primary Keys for Expected Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#1).

A brief example of this approach:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("Customer", typeof(string));
dt1.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt1.Columns["ID"] };
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Ahmad" });

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("Customer", typeof(string));
dt2.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt2.Columns["ID"] };
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Mageed" });

// try without primary keys and it'll add a new record
dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

**EDIT:** regarding your comment, you could reject the changes on merged rows that were not really changed by passing the table through the code below. A method that accepts a `DataTable` would be neater. It's important that this code is used prior to calling the [`DataTable.AcceptChanges()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx), otherwise the row states will be discarded.

With LINQ:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
    {
        var original = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                          .Select(c => row[c, DataRowVersion.Original]);

        bool isUnchanged = row.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(original);
        if (isUnchanged)
        {
            row.RejectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

If LINQ isn't an option:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
    {
        bool isUnchanged = true;
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
        {
            if (!row[col.ColumnName].Equals(row[col.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original]))
            {
                isUnchanged = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isUnchanged)
        {
            row.RejectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

You can call `dt1.AcceptChanges()` after this is done.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated so that the primary keys are set.  Now, supposed that dt1 and dt2 have the same entry for ID=100.  When dt2 is merged into dt1, it is marking it as "modified."  Is there a way to ignore these "modifications" if the data is the same?